# Domain redirection and suspension

Tags: php, dns, subdomain, redirect

I have a site developed in ASP.NET and hosted on a windows server using shared windows hosting account at godaddy.

I developed a replica of my website in php and hosted my php site on a free hosting service (php, linux, mysql) and its working fine. This is on a shared subdomain. Example (mysite.freehostprovider.com)

Now I want to continue using the free hosting service. So I would like my site to be redirected from www.mysite.com to mysite.freehostprovider.com

Since I have not paid for Windows hosting. They have stopped hosting for my site. But my domain is valid till 2010. What do I need to do to see my website go live @ www.mysite.com

My free hosting provider supports redirection. I tried but wasn't successful.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable forwarding or redirection from your domain registrar. If it is GoDaddy you are using then check out the "Forwarding a Domain" portion of this support article (page 4): http://help.godaddy.com/article/2227

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would CNAME www.mysite.com to mysite.freehostprovider.com, but a free hosting provider might not let you do that (they'll be using vhosts, so you can't just go ahead and do it).

You should probably give the redirection another go.